# How can i add a new Youtube Channel to a YouTube CMS via API?

Tags: php, youtube, content-management-system, youtube-api, google-api

Is there a function in the Google API´s to add a new YouTube channel into a YouTube CMS Account?
If not, is there any other way to add a new YouTube Channel to a YouTube CMS via my own Application so i don't need to use the form on the CMS Website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is not supported via any API.

Comment: Hey Jeff, now the CMS got merged into the YouTube Dashboard / Content Owner Dashboard and the old cms.youtube.com is shutdown, is there a way to manage my channels in my CMS via API?

Comment: I am not aware of any new API functionality related to this that's been released since my original answer.